# How to change d-none class to d-block in jquery on hover?

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would show and hide a button on edit when hovering a div. Like WordPress.

How to display a `div` inside a `div` if hovered? I'm trying to do this but there's something wrong, nothing appears.

```
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center" id="company">
    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
        <div class="p-5">
            <h1>Company</h1>
            <p class="text-justify">Description</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning rounded-pill text-danger btn-lg">Start</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
        <img src="/images/layer.png" alt="Company" class="img-fluid lazy">
    </div>
    <div class="p-5">
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">وEdit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div

<script>
    $("#company").hover(function(){
        $("#menu").css("d-none", "d-block");
    });
</script>
```

[wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKItP.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Javascript for this. You can do it all in CSS. The first rule below defaults to hiding the menu. The second rule overrides the first rule to show the menu when you hover over the `#company` div.

```
#menu {
  display: none; /* Default */
}

#company:hover #menu {
  display: block;
}
```

If you want to do it with Javascript/jQuery, you must specify separate actions for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, to ensure the menu shows/hides accordingly:

```
$("#company").hover(
  function() {
   $("#menu").css("display", "block");
  },
  function() {
   $("#menu").css("display", "none");
  },
);
```

If you want to use purely Bootstrap classes rather than manipulating the CSS style rules directly:

```
$("#company").hover(
  function() {
   $("#menu").addClass('d-block').removeClass('d-none');
  },
  function() {
   $("#menu").addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-block');
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi your code is almost correct.In your Jquery part you have to use addClass() instead of css() because you are trying to change the class name of the element.Just try this one.Hope this works

```
     <script>
        $("#company").hover(function () {
          $("#menu").addClass("d-none");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the css can be added to the "menu" id

```
#menu {
  display: none;
}
```

using js:

```
$("#company").hover(function () {
   $("#menu").css("display", "block");
});
```